# Finite Epsilon Deltas and Finding Limits Multivariable

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

[image]
[image]

Solution to 70 et 71 respectively:

[image]

I don't understand why we know $|y/(x^2+1)|$ <= |y| in problem 70. I think 
$|y/(x^2+1)|$ <= |y+x| is actually the case then let delta be half of .05.

I don't know how we knew that $|x+y/(x^2+1)|$ $<=|x+y|$ rather than $|x+y/(x^2+1)|$ $<=|y|$ in the solution of problem 71 and let delta be .01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x^2 \geqslant 0 \Rightarrow x^2+1 \geqslant 1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{x^2+1} \leqslant 1 \Rightarrow \frac{|y|}{x^2+1} \leqslant |y|   $$

The same inequality is also  used  in the second example.